# Mutex.waitOne always returns False on particular machine

Tags: c#, .net, service, mutex

I am totally stumped here. I have a chunk of code that relies on a mutex to protect it. When i run this chunk of code on my development machine and my test machine it works fine. But when i push it to the production machine it fails.

But here's the kicker, it used to work and i didn't make any code changes to this particular block. 
But wait there's more! I have a second process that uses literally the exact same block of code and it works just fine!

The mutex is declared as such:

```
Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(false, "SendTextMessage_11A52B63-4FC6-46DF-B72C-C45B225D4143");
```

The block of code using it is this:

```
        public override void ForwardTextMessagesToDevice()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Here1");
        if (!_mutex.WaitOne(30000))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Here2");
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("return mutex ForwardTextMessage: {0} {1}", this.Name, DateTime.Now));
            return; 
        }
        try
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Here3");
            ScheduledReports();
        }
        finally
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Here4");
            _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```

The trace output is this:

```
Here1
Here2
return mutex ForwardTextMessage: Method 2/11/2013 3:59:06 PM
Here1
Here2
return mutex ForwardTextMessage: Method 2/11/2013 4:00:06 PM
```

The Mutex appears to be locked immediately right out of the gate. I'm under the impression that mutex's are only shared between threads and are destroyed when the process exits so two separate processes sharing the same mutex should be good, right? Also if the application crashed before the mutex was released could it cause this behavior?

EDIT: I almost forgot. Randomly previously my application had crashed hard and i had to force quit it.

Comment: "Randomly previously my application had crashed hard and i had to force quit it. " - wow, and you weren't bothered by that? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Mutex appears to be locked immediately right out of the gate. I'm under the impression that mutex's are only shared between threads and are destroyed when the process exits so two separate processes sharing the same mutex should be good, right?

No.  *Named* Mutex instances are shared between all processes.  Another process can have the mutex locked.

From the documentation of the [Mutex constructor you are using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01985e8f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Mutexes are of two types: local mutexes and named system mutexes. If you create a Mutex object using a constructor that accepts a name, it is associated with an operating-system object of that name. Named system mutexes are visible throughout the operating system, and can be used to synchronize the activities of processes.

As for your second question:

> Also if the application crashed before the mutex was released could it cause this behavior?

This is covered by the documentation for [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01985e8f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If a thread terminates while owning a mutex, the mutex is said to be abandoned. The state of the mutex is set to signaled and the next waiting thread gets ownership. If no one owns the mutex, the state of the mutex is signaled. Beginning in version 2.0 of the .NET Framework, an AbandonedMutexException is thrown in the next thread that acquires the mutex. Prior to version 2.0 of the .NET Framework, no exception was thrown.

In the scenario where an application terminates, the mutex should be flagged as abandoned.  Attempting to acquire the `Mutex` should raise an `AbandonedMutexException`.

Comment: Hmm that is odd. Farther up the call line is a catch that should write the exception to trace but that doesn't happen. Even process explorer says 0 exceptions have occurred. The code is most definitely compiled in .net 3.5. I tried appending a 1 to the end of the mutex and it works now.